# How to map self-reference with Mapster?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mapster

I have list with items contained self reference. 
For example:
Model

```
public class Stock{
  public int StockId { get; set; }
  public int? ParentStockId { get; set; }
  public int Level { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class StockViewModel {
  public int Level { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<StockViewModel> SubStock { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data

```
var stocks = new List<Stock> {
    new Stock{ StockId = 1, Level = 10, Name = "Root1" },
    new Stock{ StockId = 2, Level = 10, Name = "Root2" },
    new Stock{ StockId = 3, ParentStockId = 1, Level = 20, Name = "Area1" },
    new Stock{ StockId = 4, ParentStockId = 2, Level = 20, Name = "Area2" },
    new Stock{ StockId = 5, ParentStockId = 3, Level = 30, Name = "Box11" },
    new Stock{ StockId = 6, ParentStockId = 3, Level = 30, Name = "Box12" },
    new Stock{ StockId = 7, ParentStockId = 4, Level = 30, Name = "Box21" }
};
```

I use a similar code to achieve the desired result. But I'm sure it's wrong. I have to make a configuration before each new request.

```
        var mapper = new Mapper(); 
        TypeAdapterConfig<Stock, StockViewModel>
            .NewConfig()
            .Map(dst => dst.SubStock, src => stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == src.StockId).ToList());
        var viewStocks = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Stock>, IEnumerable<StockViewModel>>(stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == null));
        // Sample output
        foreach (var stock in viewStocks){
            Console.WriteLine(stock.Level.ToString() + " " + stock.Name);
            if (stock.SubStock != null) 
                foreach (var stock1 in stock.SubStock){
                    Console.WriteLine("  " + stock1.Level.ToString() + " " + stock1.Name);
                    if (stock1.SubStock != null) 
                        foreach (var stock2 in stock1.SubStock){
                            Console.WriteLine("    " + stock2.Level.ToString() + " " + stock2.Name);
                        }
                }
        }
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hUhmUZ)
How to map `viewStocks` hierarhical?
Same as

```
10 Root1
  20 Area1
    30 Box11
    30 Box12
10 Root2
  20 Area2
    30 Box21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For correctly separate the configuration and map, I passing a parameter with a `stocks`

```
var viewStocks = stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == null)
            .BuildAdapter()
            .AddParameters("paramKey", stocks)
            .AdaptToType<List<StockViewModel>>();
```

and my config

```
TypeAdapterConfig<Stock, StockViewModel>
            .NewConfig()
            .Map(dst => dst.SubStock, 
                 src => ((IEnumerable<Stock>)MapContext.Current.Parameters["paramKey"])
                 .Where(x => x.ParentStockId == src.StockId)
                 .BuildAdapter()
                 .AddParameters("paramKey", MapContext.Current.Parameters["paramKey"])
                 .AdaptToType<List<StockViewModel>>());
```

[full example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMA08q)

Now in my configuration i don't need to know about `stocks`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to configure `Mapster` config for each new request. According to https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Config-location:

> Configuration should be set only once and reuse for mapping.
>   Therefore, we should not keep configuration and mapping in the same
>   location.Configuration should keep in entry point such as `Main` function or `Global.asax.cs` or `Startup.cs`.

So that you can move that mapping to entry point:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<Stock, StockViewModel>
    .NewConfig()
    .Map(dst => dst.SubStock, src => stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == src.StockId).ToList());
```

Furthermore, in order to seperate your config and mapping instance instead of this

```
 var viewStocks = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Stock>, IEnumerable<StockViewModel>>(stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == null));
```

I prefer to use `Adapt` as follows :

```
var socksWithoutParent = stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == null);
var viewStocks = socksWithoutParent.Adapt<List<StockViewModel>>();
```

Full example [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UHsJlk), it will give you same output:

```
10 Root1
  20 Area1
    30 Box11
    30 Box12
10 Root2
  20 Area2
    30 Box21
```

Comment: I understand that you need to separate the configuration and mapping. However, I do not have access to `stocks` in the configuration. how to pass `stocks` to mapping and use it in configuration?

Comment: As I pointed out you don't need to access this stocks configuration: `var viewStocks = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Stock>, IEnumerable<StockViewModel>>(stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == null));` just remove this configuration and use `Adapt`

Comment: In my project on .net core 2.1 `stocks`(StocksContorller.cs) exists only in action. In configuration(startup.cs) `stocks` doesn't exists and i don't write `TypeAdapterConfig<Stock, StockViewModel>
    .NewConfig()
    .Map(dst => dst.SubStock, src => stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == src.StockId).ToList());`

Comment: I really don't understand why you can't write `TypeAdapterConfig<Stock, StockViewModel>     .NewConfig()     .Map(dst => dst.SubStock, src => stocks.Where(x => x.ParentStockId == src.StockId).ToList());` in startup.cs. You just need add namespace of `Stock` and `StockViewModel` in order to write that configuration, that's all.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822037/where-to-put-mapster-mapping-code-in-ef-core-3-and-asp-net-mvc-core how to write configuration in startup.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cbxuem)
in this example, I can correctly separate the configuration and map